# Is it possible to use the Google Sheets JavaScript API WITHOUT user consent or auth tokens

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Background: I know it is possible to read/write data from/to a Google sheet using the JavaScript API. I know it is possible to do it with an API key paired with oAuth (because the service has to know who the user is, which really means being a google user).

However, the question that Google does not address clearly (and I find the documentation misleading):

**Can a JavaScript app/webpage have write permission to a google sheet (that is public open access) WITHOUT having to provide an oAuth client ID?**

Everything I tried and researched leads to *no, you cannot - you have to provide a client ID*. Also I find the Service Account method not applicable for JS API via a web page.

Am I missing totally missing something? Please let me know if you have any specific insight into the above.

I solved it by having middleware php code that takes data from the webpage and uses a Service Account to communicate with the Google sheet, then returns data to the webpage. So... my question re-phrased: can I do the above directly without php?

Comment: Is the Google sheet public or private?

Comment: I've no idea, to be honest. But I suppose that there is no way to do it without oAuth, otherwise creating bots that mess up random public sheets would be too easy

Comment: is it to access the sheets in ur account or of the users?

Comment: Have you checked the [Authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)  when using Sheets API? that documentation may give you an idea about what type of authorization is needed for your app.

Answer (score 0):

After testing it seems that there is no way to use `Sheets API` without getting some sort of consent being either through a [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) or by using an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey), your code will either have to show a consent screen to grant authorization or as you are currently doing, perform domain wide authority with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).